# Linq lambda joining a column in one table to three columns in another

Tags: c#, linq

I need to write a LINQ query joining one DataTable column to a value that is in one of three possible columns in another DataTable.

The below works but doesn't seem quite right. Is there a better way?

```
        var query = dtDescriptions.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupJoin(dtProducts.AsEnumerable(),
                idA => idA.Field<string>("idA"),
                productid => productid.Field<string>("Product ID"),
                (idA, productid) => new { IDA = idA, PRODUCTID = productid })
            .GroupJoin(dtProducts.AsEnumerable(),
                idB => idB.IDA.Field<string>("idB"),
                productid => productid.Field<string>("Product ID"),
                (idB, productid) => new { IDB = idB, PRODUCTID = productid })
            .GroupJoin(dtProducts.AsEnumerable(),
                idC => idC.idB.IDA.Field<string>("idC"),
                productid => productid.Field<string>("Product ID"),
                (idC, productid) => new { IDC = idC, PRODUCTID = productid });
```

Comment: Why aren't you using Entity Framework Core? This would be so much easier there, you could add navigation properties to your models, and you wouldn't need all those joins. You could also get rid of those hard-coded strings for your property names (which you probably could do now by using `nameof`, but it would still be cleaner in EF)

Comment: This is an application that reads XML files into DataTables and presents them in grids for viewing.

Comment: Why not read them into models? My point was that navigation properties would make your Linq easier. Even if the data is coming from XML files, navigation properties would still help you.

Comment: Don't use all caps for your property names. Why are you using `GroupJoin` instead of `Join`, is it possible for more than one product to match e.g. `IDA`?

Answer (score 0):

This seems much better:

```
        var query = dtdescriptions.AsEnumerable()
            .SelectMany(x =>
                    new[] { x.Field<string>("idA"), x.Field<string>("idB"), x.Field<string>("idC") }.Distinct(),
                (x, a) => new
                {
                    id = a,
                    bringanotherfieldifneeded = x.Field<string>("Other Field")
                }
            ).Join(dtProducts.AsEnumerable(),
                descriptions => descriptions.id,
                products => products.Field<string>("Product ID"),
                (descriptions, products) => new { DESCRIPTIONS = descriptions, PRODUCTS = products });
```

Comment: Why is this better? Please consider adding supporting information why this solves the issue asked in the question.

Comment: It solves the problem. I needed to find matching rows between descriptions and products. The matching ID number in descriptions could be in one of three columns. This brings all the values from the three id columns in dtdescriptions into one id column. Then I can join that column to Product ID in in Products. I can also bring over any additional fields I need from dtdescriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your chain of `Join` methods by flattening the intermediate results, but that wouldn't really lessen the redundancy. Sometimes it is better to use a cartesian product and then filter the results.

Using query syntax, you could have:

```
var q = from desc in dtDescriptions.AsEnumerable()
        from prod in dtProducts.AsEnumerable()
        where new[] {
                    desc.Field<string>("idA"),
                    desc.Field<string>("idB"),
                    desc.Field<string>("idC")
                }
                .Contains(prod.Field<string>("Product ID"))
        select new { desc, prod };
```

Or using fluent syntax:

```
var ql = dtDescriptions.AsEnumerable()
            .SelectMany(desc => dtProducts.AsEnumerable().Select(prod => new { desc, prod }))
            .Where(dp => new[] {
                       dp.desc.Field<string>("idA"),
                       dp.desc.Field<string>("idB"),
                       dp.desc.Field<string>("idC")
                   }
                   .Contains(dp.prod.Field<string>("Product ID")));
```

NOTE: If you want to keep track of which field matched, that would be a little more involved.

Comment: Thanks, I already implemented the answer I came up with on my own, but I will definitely try this out. I unfortunately have a few instances in my application where I have to make these types of comparisons, so I wanted to make sure I had a nice clean way of doing it.